# IntelliJ Idea: Red Light Bulb Behavior

Tags: intellij-idea

When there's an error in code, it gets red underlined. When I move the mouse over the error and wait a moment I get the red bulb at the left edge of the editor.

Problem is, the red bulb suddenly disappears before I move the mouse to it and doesn't come back until I move the mouse around and wait again for a few seconds over the error.

Is there a way to make the red bulb appear instantaneously when an error is found and stay visible until the error is fixed ?

Comment: It should not disappear when you move the mouse: https://i.imgur.com/GkvTw7N.gifv. You can also invoke it again using Alt+Enter.

Comment: Right, it disappears when I click elsewhere. The question stands though, I'm looking for a way to fix the light bulb in place until the error is gone or set the reappear time to zero. I hope this is possible ? (Couldn't find anything in preferences, so no ?) (edit: to make it clearer, bulb should be visible even when cursor is not placed on the error)

Comment: Not possible, related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155701.